# Google Console - API key usage is really high when app is in development

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-client

I've build a small web app that asks a user to perform a Google OAuth login and submit their data in a form to a cloud function. All of this is using the same API Key but I'm seeing the usage in the last 30 days to be 2000+ when it's just me testing it. When I look at the usage of the cloud function I see 300 (which looks more realistic to me).

The API Key usage says it includes billable and non-billable requests, any way I can actually see the breakdown without having a surprise slap me in the face at the end of the month once the app goes live?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)[image: API credentials screen]

Comment: What do you want to have? The split between the billable and non billable requests?

Comment: Can't you use two API keys, one for billable and one for non-billable?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere - yes, ideally the split

Comment: @lamblichus - I'd prefer to find the split as oppose to changing my code - I'm curious to know if there is a way of viewing the split within the cloud logs or similar so i can be certain I won't be charged

Comment: .... I think you can't have the details, especially if it's not API managed by your project (I mean MAPS API, ML API,...)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere even OAuth?

Comment: API Key is different of OAuth. No relation between both!

Comment: Have you considered contacting G Suite support, in order to clarify the reason behind this amount of usage?